# Mediation: Significant Indirect Effect But Nonsignificant Total Effect and Nonsignificant Direct Effect

Tags: mediation

I'm trying to interpret the results of a mediation I ran using 10,000 bootstraps.

In my results, the a-path was significant and positive (b = 0.07) and the b-path was significant and negative (b = -0.50). The indirect effect was small, negative, and significant (-0.03), but the direct effect was nonsignificant (-0.03) and the total effect was also nonsignificant (-0.06).

I'm a little bit confused about these results. Since the total effect is the sum of the indirect + direct effect, shouldn't the total effect also be significant when the indirect effect is significant?

Likewise, I'm wondering if it can still be considered meaningful or important to know that the indirect effect is significant when the direct effect and total effect are not significant.

Comment: You seem to switch between at least three different kinds of notation and terminology.  Could you please use one consistent set of names and terms for your variables and spell out the abbreviations?

Comment: Sorry about that! I have edited my post to try to make it clearer.

Comment: Are you writing "b = 0.07" to refer to a *p-value?*  Or would that mean something else; and if so, what?  Is your question related to https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/185626?