# What does it mean when the total effect is non-significant in a mediation?

Tags: mediation, lavaan

I ran a mediation analysis using lavaan, there was a significant indirect effect but no significant direct or total effect. What does the total effect mean and how do I go about interpreting this result? Appreciate the help!

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/185626/what-if-path-c-isnt-significant-but-paths-a-and-b-are-indirect-effect-in-medi) help?